# Insert N random values into table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I need to insert `@N` rows with random `float` values into one table and use IDs of every new inserted row for another `INSERT`. All this I need to do in stored procedure. For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc
    @N int
AS

-- START LOOP, REPEAT @N TIMES
INSERT INTO [T1]
    ([Value])
VALES
    (<random_float>)

INSERT INTO [T2]
    ([ValueID])
VALUES
    (@@IDENTITY)
-- END LOOP

END
GO
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Random float between what bounds? Also is there a maximum for `@N` beyond which you don't expect to have to go?

Comment: Bounds don't matter. For example, `@min` and `@max`. No limit for `@N`

Comment: From a practical perspective there will be a limit for `@N`. Are you ever going to use this to insert a trillion rows?

Comment: @Martin, I am interested in method only. Max value for `@N` is another business, is not my question about.

Comment: The reason for asking is in order to be able to give you a less RBAR approach. Inserting single rows in a loop is highly inefficient...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No loops, one insert

```
;WITH cte AS
(  --there are easier ways to build a numbers table
   SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 0)) AS rn
   FROM
      sys.columns c1 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c2 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c3
)
INSERT INTO [T1] ([Value])
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID INTO T2  -- direct insert to T2
SELECT RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= @N;
```

Comment: @@gbn: is the OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);  required?

Comment: It doesn't insert to `T2` though?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: good point, non-recursive CTEs don't need. Thanks

Comment: @Martin Smith: overlooked that, fixed, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do. Did you mean something like this:

```
create table dbo.RandomTable
( 
    rowid int not null PRIMARY KEY,        
    pure_random float null,
)

declare @row int
set @row = 1
while (@row <= @N)
begin
   insert into dbo.RandomTable (rowid, pure_random)
   values (@row, rand())
   set @row = @row + 1
end
```

[I'm not advocating the use of a loop; it's not the most efficient way of doing this. It's just that's the form the poster was asking for...]

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE [T1]
(
    [ValueID] INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    [Value] FLOAT
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [T2]
(
    [ValueID] INT
)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [Proc]
    @N int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @i INT = 0;

    WHILE (@i < @N)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [T1]
            ([Value])
        SELECT RAND()

        INSERT INTO [T2]
            ([ValueID])
        VALUES
            (SCOPE_IDENTITY())

        SET @i += 1
    END
END
GO

TRUNCATE TABLE T1
TRUNCATE TABLE T2
EXEC [Proc] @N = 10
```

See [WHILE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx), and [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx).