# Inserting random number of rows in SQL Server via join to integer list is inconsistent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a database with sample data. Each time I run the stored procedure to generate some new data for my sample database, I would like to clear out and repopulate table B ("Item") based on all the rows in table A ("Product").

If table A contained the rows with primary key values 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, I would want table B to have a foreign key for table A and insert a random number of rows into table B for each table A row. (We are essentially stocking the shelves with a random number of "item" for any given "product.")

I am using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7544950/394326) to generate a list of numbers. I join to the results of this function to create the rows to insert:

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (select 0)) AS i
   FROM
      sys.columns c1 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c2 CROSS JOIN sys.columns c3
)
SELECT i
FROM cte
WHERE 
    i BETWEEN @p_Min AND @p_Max AND
    i % @p_Increment = 0
```

Random numbers are generated in a view (to get around the limitations of functions) as follows:

```
-- Mock.NewGuid view
SELECT id = ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY) AS INT)))
```

And a function that returns the random numbers:

```
-- Mock.GetRandomInt(min, max) function definition
DECLARE @random int;
SELECT @random = Id % (@MaxValue - @MinValue + 1) FROM Mock.NewGuid;
RETURN @random + @MinValue;
```

However, when you look at this code and execute it...

```
WITH Products AS
(
    SELECT ProductId, ItemCount = Mock.GetRandomInt(1,5)
    FROM Product.Product
)
SELECT A = Products.ProductId, B = i
FROM Products
JOIN (SELECT i FROM Mock.GetIntList(1,5,1)) Temp ON
    i < Products.ItemCount
ORDER BY ProductId, i
```

... this returns some inconsistent results!

```
A,B
1,1
1,2
1,3
2,1
2,2
3,2 <-- where is 1?
3,3
4,1
5,3 <-- where is 1, 2?
6,1
```

I would expect that, for every product id, the JOIN results in 1-5 rows. However, it seems like values get skipped! This is even more apparent with larger data sets. I was originally trying to generate 20-50 rows in Item for each Product row, but this resulted in only 30-40 rows for each product.

**The question:** Any idea why this is happening? Each product should have a random number of rows (between 1 and 5) inserted for it and the B value should be sequential! Instead, some numbers are missing!

This issue also happens if I store numbers in a table I created and then join to that, or if I use a recursive CTE.

I am using SQL Server 2008R2, but I believe I see the same issue on my 2012 database as well. Compatibility levels are 2008 and 2012 respectively.

Comment: It looks like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to `GetIntList` fixes the problem I am having, but I don't know why that is the case. If anyone could explain that... awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to GetIntList (as opposed to `INNER JOIN`) fixes the problem I am having.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun problem.  I've dealt with this in a round about way a number of times.  I am sure there is a way to not use a cursor.  But why not.  This is a cheap problem memory wise so long as the @RandomMaxRecords doesn't get huge or you have a significant amount of product records.  If the data in the Items table is meaningless then I would suggest truncating any in memory table where I define the hash table for #Item.  And obviously you will pull from your Product table not the hash I have created for testing.

This is a fantastic article and describes in detail how I arrive at my solution.  [Less Than Dot Blog](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/sql-server-set-based-random-numbers)

**CODE**

```
--This is your product table with 5 random products
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Product') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Product
CREATE TABLE #Product
(
    ProductID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    ProductName VARCHAR(25),
    ProductDescription VARCHAR(max)
)
INSERT INTO #Product (ProductName,ProductDescription) VALUES ('Product Name 1','Product Description 1'),
                                                             ('Product Name 2','Product Description 2'),
                                                             ('Product Name 3','Product Description 3'),
                                                             ('Product Name 4','Product Description 4'),
                                                             ('Product Name 5','Product Description 5')

--This is your item table.  This would probably just be a truncate statement so that your table is reset for the new values to go in
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Item') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Item
CREATE TABLE #Item
(
    ItemID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    FK_ProductID INT NOT NULL,
    ItemName VARCHAR(25),
    ItemDescription VARCHAR(max)
)

--Declare a bunch of variables for the cursor and insert into the item table process
DECLARE @ProductID INT
DECLARE @ProductName VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @ProductDescription VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @RandomItemCount INT
DECLARE @RowEnumerator INT
DECLARE @RandomMaxRecords INT = 10

--We declare a cursor to iterate over the records in product and generate random amounts of items
DECLARE ItemCursor CURSOR
FOR SELECT * FROM #Product

OPEN ItemCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM ItemCursor INTO @ProductID, @ProductName, @ProductDescription
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
BEGIN

    --Get the Random Number into the variable.  And we only want 1 or more records.  Mod division will produce a 0.
    SELECT @RandomItemCount = ABS(CHECKSUM(NewID())) % @RandomMaxRecords
    SELECT @RandomItemCount = CASE @RandomItemCount WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE @RandomItemCount END

    --Iterate on the RowEnumerator to the RandomItemCount and insert item rows
    SET @RowEnumerator = 1
    WHILE (@RowEnumerator <= @RandomItemCount)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #Item (FK_ProductID,ItemName,ItemDescription)
        SELECT @ProductID, REPLACE(@ProductName,'Product','Item'),REPLACE(@ProductDescription,'Product','Item')

        SELECT @RowEnumerator = @RowEnumerator + 1
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM ItemCursor INTO @ProductID, @ProductName, @ProductDescription
END

CLOSE ItemCursor
DEALLOCATE ItemCursor
GO

--Look at the result
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    #Product AS P
    RIGHT JOIN #Item AS I ON (P.ProductID = I.FK_ProductID)

--Cleanup
DROP TABLE #Product
DROP TABLE #Item
```

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate example. However, I think I've managed to do it without a cursor using the chunks of SQL I provided. The problem is that the join behavior of products to the integer list is returning results that aren't quite right. I'm curious why I experience that specific issue.

Comment: No worries.  I had a working example as I mentioned I have dealt with this problem a few times now.  Cursors provided me the most control and despite their bad rap (I almost never recommend using cursors) in this particular case it really isn't that offensive memory wise.  The part of your solution I am hung up on is the INNER JOIN from product to your Item table.  Can't say for sure though.

Comment: It turns out that using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` makes it work. Hopefully MSDN holds the answer to this because I have no idea why an `OUTER JOIN` would be needed.